# How do i use nativescript load on demand funtion

Tags: javascript, nativescript

**EDIT**

i was able to get it to work, but one problem now is, before it creates and additional empty item before showing other items. 
NB the load on demand function works fine, but i don't know why an additional empty item is created. i guess there's an issue with my code

```
const viewModel = observableModule.fromObject({
    _sourceDataItems: [],
    dataItems: new ObservableArray(),
    initDataItems: function () {
      var url="https://adekunletestprojects.000webhostapp.com/skog/searchResults.php?search=" + encodeURIComponent("Adeyeye") + "&location=" + encodeURIComponent("Lagos");
      fetch(url).then((response) => response.json()).then((res) => {
        this._sourceDataItems = new ObservableArray(res.items);
        this.dataItems.push(this._sourceDataItems);

      }).catch((err) => {
        var toast = Toast.makeText("Unable to load users");
        toast.show();
      });
    },
    addMoreItemsFromSource: function (chunkSize) {
      console.log(this._sourceDataItems);
      let newItems = this._sourceDataItems.splice(0, chunkSize);
      this.dataItems.push(newItems);
    },

    onLoadMoreItemsRequested: function (args) {
      console.log("---load more item---");
      const that = new WeakRef(this);
      const listView = args.object;
      if (this._sourceDataItems.length > 0) {
        setTimeout(function () {
          that.get().addMoreItemsFromSource(10);
          listView.notifyLoadOnDemandFinished();
        }, 1500);
        args.returnValue = true;
      } else {
        args.returnValue = false;
        listView.notifyLoadOnDemandFinished(true);
      }
    },
});
```

Comment: Your `dataItems` should be an ObservableArray and you should just push the new items to the array, reassigning it will reload whole list.

Comment: @Manoj THANK YOU!, i've updated the question. kindly review it

Comment: Please share a Playground sample.

Comment: @Manoj [playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=TkJ6IS&v=13) thanks

Comment: It's because of `this.dataItems.push(this._sourceDataItems);` You are using entire ObservableArray into it. I'm not even sure why you had do that. I would highly recommend you know read the docs before using a method.

Comment: @Manoj `this.dataItems.push(this._sourceDataItems);` - i did that cause without it, it was not displaying the items at all. i have checked all the examples even your contribution [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56824342/how-the-nativescript-radlist-view-load-on-demand-works). Please what can i do to correct this

Comment: There is a huge difference between the codes, in my sample I pushed array into it and in yours you are pushing the observable array itself into another.

Comment: @Manoj oh, i've pushed just `res.items` now, the load on demand  doesn't work. please check [link](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=TkJ6IS&v=45)

Comment: @Manoj nevermind, fixed it already, will share the final code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search-view-model.js

```
_sourceDataItems: new ObservableArray(),
    dataItems: new ObservableArray(),
    initDataItems: function () {
      var url = "https://adekunletestprojects.000webhostapp.com/skog/searchResults.php?search=" + encodeURIComponent("Adeyeye") + "&location=" + encodeURIComponent("Lagos");
      fetch(url).then((response) => response.json()).then((res) => {
        this._sourceDataItems = res.items; 
        this.addMoreItemsFromSource(6);
      }).catch((err) => {
        alert(err.message);
      });
    },
    addMoreItemsFromSource: function (chunkSize) {
      console.log(this._sourceDataItems);
      let newItems = this._sourceDataItems.splice(0, chunkSize);
      this.dataItems.push(newItems);
    },

    onLoadMoreItemsRequested: function (args) {
      console.log("---load more item---");
      const that = new WeakRef(this);
      const listView = args.object;
      if (this._sourceDataItems.length > 0) {
        setTimeout(function () {
          that.get().addMoreItemsFromSource(10);
          listView.notifyLoadOnDemandFinished();
        }, 1500);
        args.returnValue = true;
      } else {
        args.returnValue = false;
        listView.notifyLoadOnDemandFinished(true);
      }

    },
```

Search.js

```
exports.pageLoaded = function (args) {
  const page = args.object;
  var searchViewModel = new SearchViewModel();
  page.bindingContext = searchViewModel;
  searchViewModel.initDataItems();
  searchViewModel.addMoreItemsFromSource(5);
}
```